# Finding the merge point of two singlyLinkedlist using an array which stores the address of each Node of linked list

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list

Problem is to find the merge point of two linked list using an array which stores the value of address of each node of a linked list.

i have tried increasing the size of address of changing the head pointer but doesnt seems to help for long linked lists.

```
int findMergeNode(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode **a;
    a=(SinglyLinkedListNode**)malloc(200*sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));
    int i=0;
    while(head1){
      a[i]=head1;
      head1=head1->next;
      i++;
    }
    while(head2){
     SinglyLinkedListNode *p=head2;
     for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(a[j]==p){
          return p->data;
        }
      }
      head2=head2->next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: To do the task there is no need to create an array. Moreover the using the magic number 200 is unclear.

Comment: Yea thnx i got the problem the list can be of even bigger size then 200.and Yea i know it is not the best and the optimal solution.

Comment: The current code returns the `data` from the node. Wouldn't it be more useful to return a pointer to the node (and return `NULL` if there is no merge point)? You can easily get the `data` value from the merged node pointer, but going the other way is harder, especially if the `data` values are not unique.

Comment: There is no need to create an array (extra space), although this is one of those problems where faster than naive algorithms can be used at the expense of using extra space.

Comment: OT: regarding: `a=(SinglyLinkedListNode**)malloc(200*sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));`  1) In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2)  Always check (!=NULL)  the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "malloc failed" );` to output both your error message and the reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: When asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: `a=(SinglyLinkedListNode**)malloc(200*sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));`.  This does NOT produce a singly linked list rather, it produces an array with room for 200 entries.  Much better to just do: `SinglyLinkedListNode **a = NULL;` then use `realloc()` to extend the size as each node is added.

Comment: regarding: `SinglyLinkedListNode *p=head2;
     for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(a[j]==p){
          return p->data;`  This is not producing a 'merged' list rather, it is producing a `intersection` of the lists

Comment: why not just walk down to the end of the first linked list, then set the 'next' field of the last node to point to the first node in the second list?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing only one part of your post here:

The statement

```
a=(SinglyLinkedListNode**)malloc(200*sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));
```

has a couple of potential problems.
1) If you are expecting this to create memory for an addressable array of arrays it is not be doing what you expect it to do.
2) casting the return of calloc is not necessary (or recommended) in C.  (in C++, it is)

Creating an addressable array of arrays of any type variable can be done in many ways, the following is one example:

```
TYPE ** Create2D(ssize_t numArrays, ssize_t maxArrayLen)
{
    int i;
    TYPE **a = {0};
    a = calloc(numArrays, sizeof(TYPE *));
    for(i=0;i<numArrays; i++)
    {
      a[i] = calloc(maxArrayLen + 1, 1);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Where TYPE is any C type, such as `char`, `int`, `float`, or in this case `SinglyLinkedListNode`.  Just replace *TYPE* with any real type and the function will create an array of arrays, such as:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode **a;
a = Create2D(20, 200);//create 20 arrays, each with 200 elements
```

each element accessible via array notation: `a[i][j]`

Dont forget to free when done.

Answer (score 0):

```
int findMergeNode(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2)
{
    SinglyLinkedListNode *temp = head2;
        while(head1) {
            head2 = temp;
            while(head2) {
                if(head1 == head2) {
                    return head2->data;
                 }
                 head2 = head2->next;
            }
            head1 = head1->next;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```